# UIView drawRect Method with options

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-graphics

I want to create an [UIView Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html) that you can initialise with several options.

I think the problem is the `drawRect()` method. Is it possible to initialise the class with a certain option like

```
[[MyUIView alloc]initWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]]
```

I read that I should never call the `drawRect()` method without initialising an object.

So how can I realize the statement above without calling it manually?

What I have tried so far:

I thought that I could just initialize the View and then call Method

```
[MyView changeColorTo:green]
```

which tries to redraw the View however I couldn't get that to work.

Maybe it's important that I draw with `coreGraphics` (with a certain color, which should be selectable) a rounded rectangle in the `drawRect()` method.

How can I implement my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call

```
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:aCGRect];
```

that calls drawRect: for you.

Edit on the color property:

```
@interface MyView: UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *drawColor;

@end

@implementation MyView

@synthesize drawColor;

- (id)initWithWhatever
{
    self.drawColor = [UIColor infraRedColor];
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:aRect];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    // use self.drawColor
}

@end
```

Comment: If I do it like this it will draw the Default rectangle. How can I add an option to that call.

Comment: Hmm maybe its a dum question but how can I add an Option like color if I do  setNeedsDisplay with a CGRect?

Comment: @AzzUrr1 add a property to the view then set it before calling setNeedsDisplayWithRect: and check it in drawRect.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it completly but I will make some tries

Comment: can you maybe give a short example what u mean with add a property. Somehow I don't get it...

Comment: see edit, and next time please develop a bit of algorithmic thinking. This is something that should be obvious :)